# What happens when a XHTML DOCTYPE doesn't validate?

Tags: xhtml-1.0-strict, xhtml

Life is good, using XHTML Strict with much success

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

...Then, bam! You toss a Vimeo video onto your page that breaks validation.

```
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/XXXXX?byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="468" height="351" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

No iframes allowed, sir!

So, what impact does it have on the way the page renders, or impact on the visitor? Why care about the validation of this iframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't have an impact on the page itself. Unless you are worried about validation, I would stay with the transitional doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

The `iframe` validation is solely up to you. [Here is a list](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_html_dtd.asp) of elements that compare with each doctype.

Comment: That is is very helpful, but I [read](http://24ways.org/2005/transitional-vs-strict-markup) that "an additional benefit of using a Strict DOCTYPE is that doing so will ensure that browsers use their strictest, most standards compliant rendering modes." Thoughts?

Comment: I would have to agree, I also want to point out that I would prefer a strict doc type than transitional because I would benefit from validation and clean semantic structure. But inserting an iframe into a strict doc type has little effect, it will still be able to be viewed on different browsers. In your case you can choose between strict or transitional - with transitional you would have more flexibility in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to embed the Flash player it as an `<object>` instead?  Something like this:

```
<object width="400" height="300" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="url">
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
    <param name="movie" value="uri" />
</object>
```

More info here:
[Vimeo Flash Player (Moogaloop)](http://vimeo.com/api/docs/player#moogaloop)

Comment: The legacy (non-iframe) code can be [tweaked manually](http://ken-blog.krugler.org/2008/06/14/converting-vimeo-embedded-html-to-xhtml/), but I'm more interested in what happens when I "break" the doctype.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing will happen. Browsers do not validate your (X)HTML and so `<iframe>` with your XHTML strict doctype will work just fine in all browsers. But if you want standards mode, and also want `<iframe>` to validate, I suggest the HTML5 doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>`